# PySimpleGUI clear button isn't clearing the canvas. Graph remains and adds to the new graph

Tags: pysimplegui

Clear button does not clear out the matplotlib graph on canvas.  Instead it builds the new graph on top of the existing graph.

[Replit link to the source](https://replit.com/@ShahAhmed1/mainpy#main.py)

```
    #clearing all the outputs 
    if event == '-BTNCLEAR-':

        window['-OUTPUT-'].Update('')
        window['-OUTPUT1-'].Update('')
        window['-OUTPUT2-'].Update('')
        window['-OUTPUT3-'].Update('')
        ax.cla()                       # to clear the canvas
        
        #window['-CANVAS-'].update('')
        #sg.Canvas.delete("all")
    window.refresh()
        

    
    
    
window.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might forget to update the change

```py
        ax.cla()                       # to clear the canvas
        fig_agg.draw()                 # to update the change
```

Comment: also I forgot to reset the win, loss and tie variables to 0.  So added the following after ax.cla( )   if win != 0:
          win = 0
        if lose != 0:
          lose = 0
        if tie != 0:
          tie = 0

Comment: What's the difference if you use `win, lose, tie = 0, 0, 0` ?

Comment: thanks looks much cleaner